# remove duplication in data using oData

Tags: javascript, json, odata

I want to remove duplication from my data using oDATA. i am using !summary=Name but it does not make groups and returns me the result accordingly.
My query is:

```
http://localhost:12585/OData.svc/MedicalGroups?$format=application/json;odata=nometadata&$select=Id,Name&!summary=Name&$orderby=Name&filterUserId=277&$filter=not(Deleted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the model details about your EntityType "MedicalGroups"? summary is property of "MedicalGroups"? According to the OData protocol "$select=Id,Name&!summary=Name" is invalid.